# Azure Cosmos Change Feed feeding into Event Grid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventgrid, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I am using a cosmos DB and I am looking to use the change feed to send changes over an azure event grid to other databases or listeners interested in the changes.

I am sure that the cosmos DB change feed cannot be directly piped into the event grid but how do I make the change feed an event source to pipe into the event grid.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure functions. They can be setup to be triggered by any changes in your CosmosDB and transfer those changes to your Event grid topic.

CosmosDB trigger Functions [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) and Event grid output bindings [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-output?tabs=csharp).